# Parallelizing std::replace on std::deque

Tags: c++, memory, parallel-processing, deque

First of all I know that multiple writters on a deque are not very easy to handle. But with the following algorithm I can guarantee that there is no concurrent access on elements. The algorithm divides a deque (it is very large, thats the reason why I parallelize it) in chunks and the std::replaces replaces a value in the deque. The problem is, that in some cases after replacing an arbitrary value, the value seems to still exist (btw: it is NOT the case that the new value is the same as the old one). Is it maybe the case that the value is not synced out of the cpu register to the memory? Here the code:

```
std::deque<int*> _deque;
...
int threadsCount = 25;          
int chunkSize = ceil((float) _deque.size() / (float) threadsCount);                                                                                                                          
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (int threadNo = 0; threadNo < threadsCount; threadNo++) {
   std::uint64_t beginIndex = threadNo * chunkSize;
   std::uint64_t endIndex = (threadNo + 1) * chunkSize;
   if (endIndex > _deque.size()) {    
      endIndex = _deque.size();      
   }
   std::deque<int*>::iterator beginIterator = _deque.begin() + beginIndex;
   std::deque<int*>::iterator endIterator = _deque.begin() + endIndex;
   threads.push_back(std::thread([beginIterator, endIterator, elementToReplace, elementNew] () {
      std::replace(beginIterator, endIterator, elementToReplace, elementNew);                                      
   }));
}
for (int threadNo = 0; threadNo < threadsCount; threadNo++) {                                                                                                                               
   threads[threadNo].join();     
}
```

After that algorithm it is sometimes (not deterministic) the case that a replaced (elementToReplace) value is still in the deque.

Comment: FYI: Identifiers starting with `__` are reserved, you should not use them.

Comment: `begin` and `end` are both non-const member functions, and they are called concurrently, this is a data race (as governed by the interface of `deque`) regardless whether the iterators point to different objects

Comment: @Rakete1111:  Actually all identifiers *containing* `__` are reserved to the implementation for all purposes.  As are identifiers starting with `_` followed by a capital letter.

Comment: @PasserBy You are technically correct of course, but can you explain why this might cause a problem in this case?

Comment: I know the "__" are reserved. Please don't care about that. I only replaced the real name with something.

Comment: ... and do you believe that calculating `__deque.begin() + beginIndex` in the main thread would solve the problem?

Comment: @MartinBonner Calculating begin() + beginIndex/endIndex in the main thread DID NOT solve the problem. I tried it.

Comment: @MartinBonner It would resolve the calls themselves, but since I have no idea how the iterators are implemented, I don't know whether there will be no data race then.

Comment: Can I suggest you [edit] your question to replace the __ with a single _, and calculate the interators in the main thread.  Then we can discuss code that doesn't appear to invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PasserBy `begin`/`end` are required to have a O(1) complexity, so they probably just return a value. How is that going to cause a data race, because I thought that generally just concurrent reads are safe?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, but that requires knowledge of the implementation, which I don't. And there really is no guarantee since the method isn't `const`

Comment: @MartinBonner I reformatted the code and added an abstract declaration of the _deque var.

Comment: @ErhardDinhobl If I understand the problem correctly, are you saying that the deque has more elements after the threads all finished?

Comment: The calculation of endIndex is wrong, it can go beyond the maximum of the container. it should be `std::uint64_t endIndex = std::min(_deque.size(),(threadNo + 1) * chunkSize);`

Comment: @Rakete1111 The problem is, that after the algorithm finishes, the _deque still contains elements with the value from elementsToReplace!

Comment: @IlBeldus I know thats the reason why I checked "if (endIndex > _deque.size()) {"

Comment: @ErhardDinhobl But only after setting the iterator :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 the deque does not get more elements ;)

Comment: @Rakete1111 That was a typo introduced after the code is changed because of the concurrent calls to `begin` and `end`. Fixed it

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, I noticed, but still :) Important to note :)

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf34429389715ab9), which is to be expected. Looking through the requirements of `deque` iterators, I don't believe any sane implementation can cause a data race through them. Looks to me like you've got a problem somewhere else.

Comment: With a non-parallel approach it seems to work: std::replace(_deque.begin() _deque.end(), elementToReplace, elementNew);

Comment: There are many possibilities, but I doubt it's caused by `std::replace` and the iterators unless the library implementer have some sick sense of humour

Comment: I think we need a [mcve] which can be tested in multiple environments to be able to make progress on this.

Comment: Note that std::replace is going to be either cpu bound (in which case you can only usefully use as many threads as you have cores), or memory bound (in which case threads won't help at all).

Comment: Yes @MartinBonner - but the part of my question also was if it is possible that the element which was replaced is still in the register and not synced back to the memory. Since the solution without parallelization seems to work, I suppose that is a race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: Since the above algorithm crashed and the suggested execution policy is still not available on my system I used GNU parallel:

```
__gnu_parallel::replace(_deque.begin(), _deque.end(), elementToReplace, elementNew);
```

I will tell you if it worked and the performance stats.

Comment: Performance is not that good as my algorithm but it works. The supposed algo from myself did not work.

Comment: This solution also did not work. After some time the race condition again happens. ;(

Comment: normal std::replace should work now with the same performance like the parallel worked

Comment: The probleme I recognized here is, that if the RAM is full (including disk cache) the gnu parallel framework does not work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually implementing such an algorithm, just pass the appropriate execution policy:

```
std::replace(std::execution::par, deque.begin(), deque.end(), elementToReplace, elementNew);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//     executes the algorithm in parallel
```

Do note that you have to compile with C++17 or later.

Comment: Interesting! did not know that yet

Comment: Damn, not supported yet on my environment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a race condition but I can't reproduce it: http://cpp.sh/5egzm
It might be down to the deque implementation you are using but it looks odd

Comment: The algorithm runs a few days without any problems, but then it happens ;( Now it seems, that without parallelization it works without any problems.

Comment: Yep, that is what I mean, it's a clear sign of a race condition. It looks like something is making your deque re-index itself

Comment: Yea it seems like that, but for me it is strange.

Comment: @IlBeldux what do you mean with re-indexing. This is the first time I hear about a reindexing process in a deque

Comment: And: In the current implementation I use a vector no deque anymore